# The execution time form Symfony profiler is not correct?

Tags: php, symfony, time, profiler, execution

I learning Symfony and follow the doc https://symfony.com/doc/current/page_creation.html to create page, it look good but the execution time from profiler seems have big difference compare with Bowers console:

[image]

Anyone know why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Symfony profiler doesn't count the time what browser needs to display file. You have server and client side execution times. Server doesn't execute javascript files, they are interpreted by browser so times may be different.

Comment: Also when using the browser console loading times are longer. Reasons are disabled cache, everything gets logged and tracked...